# Hyper-V (Windows 11) - Disable all network access on host but not VMs

Tags: windows, networking, security, virtualization, hyper-v

Is it possible to create a setup where the Windows 11 Hyper-V VM host has all network access completely disabled, but the VMs running on it still retain full access?

In a model similar to what Qubes OS does under the hood, but on Windows...